# Android application crashes when I change the icon in Android Manifest

Tags: android

When I change the:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

to

```
 android:icon="@drawable/yellow_sun_symbol"
```

The app crashes instantly upon launch. I have already placed the different resolution pictures in the drawable folders with the correct name.

Can anyone remedy my issue?

Thanks for your help in advance

EDIT:

The logcvat file shows this:

```
12-19 08:31:23.145: W/dalvikvm(22525): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d402a0)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zstock/com.example.zstock.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3019)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3079)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:304)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at com.example.zstock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    ... 11 more
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    ... 25 more
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:476)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:672)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:641)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:151)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadDefaultIcon(ComponentInfo.java:167)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:156)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:674)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:222)
12-19 08:31:23.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    ... 28 more
```

I have spell checked the XML and everything is fine, no red lines anywhere. The file I am using is called 'yellow_sun_symbol' and it is located in all of the drawable folders under the same name, but with different resolutions.

The AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.zstock"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/yellow_sun_symbol"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sweetorange" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.zstock.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I change the @drawable/yellow_sun_symbol to @drawable_ic_launcher it works fine. There is probably some minor detail that I am missing here since I'm a total beginner at this.

Thanks in advance once more!

Comment: Read your logcat, there you will find your exception. If you cant find it, post your logcat here

Comment: Need more details to debug the issue. Post the project folder structure and the activity and xml classes

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. You sure you are using the correct name?

Comment: how big is this image because you are getting an `OutOfMemoryError` which is usually caused by an image being too big

Comment: sanity check:Are you using the proper image format?  I believe android requires your resources to PNG's.

Comment: Thanks tyczj! It turns out that the image was too big. Re-sized it and everything is fine now

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception : OutOfMemoryError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795645/exception-outofmemoryerror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from console: run "ant clean"
or manualy delete "bin" and "gen" directories from project dir